# XMPPFramework Socket closed by remote peer

Tags: ios, ssl, ios7, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm trying to implement the [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) by [robbiehanson](https://github.com/robbiehanson). The problem is, that I get the following error message:

```
Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x9517440 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
```

I already tried everything I could find on the internet (`XMPPPing` etc.) but nothing could fix my problem. Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)connect {
    stream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [stream setEnableBackgroundingSocket:YES];
    [stream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    reconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];
    [reconnect activate:stream];

    [stream setHostName:_hostName];
    [stream setPort:5223];

    [stream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:_username];

    NSError *e;
    if(![stream connectWithTimeout:20 error:&e]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", e);
    }

    - (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {
        NSError *e;
        [sender authenticateWithPassword:_password];

        if(e) {
            NSLog(@"%@", e);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error message immediately, not after several seconds. I already thought it might be, because our server requires SSL, but the only solution I found for SSL was running `[stream secureConnection:nil];` and this only works if connected.

I also never get the `-xmppStreamDidConnect:` delegate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stream oldSchoolSecureConnectWithTimeout:` will connect to 5223/SSL

Comment: I ran into the same problem and when I try this solution I got this error: `Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL Code=-9847 "(null)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Error code definition can be found in Apple's SecureTransport.h}`. What did I do wrong?